# Additional Data in Deeplink with a link to launch app

Tags: android, cordova, deep-linking

I am launching the android mobile using intent deeplink concept.

On clicking the link i.e.

```
<a href="myapp://hello">Lauch app</a>
```

But I want to pass some hidden data to the app while launching the application.

For example, I want to pass JSON data like

```
<a href="myapp://hello" data="{name:'ram',age:'20',city:'Delhi'}" >Lauch app</a>
```

How can I get the data read by my app while launching?

Or

Is there any other solution or way by which I can send a huge data to my app while launching?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Chrome Intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents):

```
<a href="intent://hello/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=your.package.name;S.payload=%7Bname%3A%27ram%27%2Cage%3A%2720%27%2Ccity%3A%27Delhi%27%7D;end">Click</a>
```

Here `S.payload` will be transferred to your app as a String extra with the key `payload`.
Note: The data must be urlencoded.

Comment: Thanks simon, what is the max size limit of the data that can be passed ?

Comment: I don't know. It certainly corresponds to the Intent Bundle maximum size (1MB I think). Try and test with long strings if you really need to.

Comment: Chrome Intents are great in theory, but only really useful if the only browser you need to support is Chrome...which is unlikely :). You could take a look at [Branch.io](https://branch.io/how-branch-links-work/). Passing data through like this is one of our specialities

Comment: Well, chrome intents have already been adopted by most browsers.